# Game goes closed completely when user press home button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I download a game developed in cocos2d from the net. Now there is a problem when i press home button then application goes quite completely.
it also called the applicationWillTerminate: method.
Now my problem is i do not want that the application quite completely when user press home button. Any help?

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [[director openGLView] removeFromSuperview];

    [viewController release];

    [window release];

    [director end]; 
}

- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}
```

Comment: Have you customised the willEnterBackground/didEnterBackground functions at all?

Comment: i check code but there is no such thing, that can close the app

Comment: In the app delegate. `-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

Comment: i had added my code for application state change

Answer (score -1):

Does the [Info.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1) contain the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`? If so, it will terminate the app and not enter background.

If you're running on a device with iOS 3.x or earlier (or the app's deployment target is set to iOS 3.x or earlier which shouldn't be possible anymore these days) the app will always terminate because background apps are not supported on iOS prior to version 4.0.

Here are [more reasons why an app may terminate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW49). Specifically if it takes too long (5+ seconds) to enter background, or if it consumes too much memory and iOS needs to free up some memory.

Comment: no, i checked but it does not UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key in info.plist